# Sqoop Export with Missing Data

Tags: sql, postgresql, shell, hadoop, sqoop

I am trying to use Sqoop to export data from HDFS into Postgresql. However, I receive an error partially through the export that it can't parse the input. I manually went into the file I was exporting and saw that this row had two columns missing. I have tried a bunch of different arguments with the Sqoop command, but cannot get it to work. Here is what I was running thus far:

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/XX -username
XX -password XX --table XX --input-fields-terminated-by
"\t" --input-lines-terminated-by "\n" --input-null-string '\n' --input-null
non-string '\n' -m 1 --export-dir /user/dan/output
```

I have also tried it without the "--input-null-string" and "--input-null-non-string" args and got the same result. My table has 6 columns and the file I am reading has tab separated values that are inserted into the table if all 6 are there. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try without `--input-fields-terminated-by
"\t" --input-lines-terminated-by "\n" --input-null-string '\n' --input-null
non-string '\n'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing my reduce function so that if there were not the correct amount of fields to output a certain value and then I was able to use the --input-null-non-string with that value and it worked.